# No VNC option on Raspbian menu

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I want to use VNC on my rpi3, in [the documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) says that vnc viewer is preinstalled but I don't find VNC graphically and even in terminal (via SSH). I have a multi boot (raspbian, osmc and retropie) that I got [here](http://www.multibootpi.com/builds/retropie-v4-0-2-raspbian-kodi-libreelec-openelec-or-osmc-you-decide/).

Really need help to use VNC on my rpii what can I do ?

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you running and when did you install it? VNC is only installed on recent versions.

Comment: Thanks for trying to helping me:
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: That does not look like the latest version. try this sudo apt-get install realVNC-VNC-server

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnupg2 : Depends: gnupg-agent (= 2.0.26-6) but 2.0.26-6+deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: I had a lot of time this error while i'm trying queries (I'm not very good at terminal commands)

Comment: have you done what the error suggests sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: I feel stupid now, thank you the VNC server is correctly installed, I also used the command to starts it.
But when I try to connect with the client it tells me that 'The connection was refused by the computer' I checked in sudo raspi-config I still don't have the option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a VNC viewer or client, is different from a server. A server mirrors its display to the client.

You can install a VNC server with `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it says: 
'E: Unable to locate package realvncserver'

Comment: This answer is confusing. The VNC server included in recent Raspbian (to which the OP's link refers) is `RealVNC`, which is incompatible with `tightvncserver`. They have a number of significant differences. Personally I use `tightvncserver`, but the [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) are not applicable to `tightvncserver`.

Answer (score 4):

This has been marked as solved however the answer doesn't answer the question. You should do

```
sudo raspi-config
```

If you don't see "Interfacing Options" then head to update. Once it's updated, reboot. Then do `sudo raspi-config` again and go to interfacing options and enable VNC. Reboot once more and it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Download VNC server from https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/

and install manually with sudo dpkg --install filename